# Add e-mail to domain alias

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, wordpress-mu

We are setting up a wordpress multi-site that allows 2 or more websites to operate from a single WP install. The way this usually works is you add the address of the 2nd website as a domain alias of the first.

This works fine however we have a problem with the client wanting a unique mailbox for the domain that is used as the alias instead of being synched with the primary domain. 
Is this possible if i am using plesk control panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain Aliases in Plesk share mailboxes (if mail aliasing is enabled). So all mailboxes are available at both `@domain.com` and `@domainalias.com`.

Still you can probably do a trick and give one user `mail1@domain.com` and another one `mail2@domainalias.com`. As long as cross-availability of `mail1@domainalias.com` and `mail2@domain.com` won't be a concern for you, your customers shouldn't have any problem - anyway they access only their own mailbox (`mail1` or `mail2`).